# PowerShell, Robocopy and SchTasks --> Send variables and text for the command

Tags: variables, powershell, scheduled-tasks, robocopy, windows-task-scheduler

I have a little problem with my Powershell backupscript.
I use the Task Scheduler with Robocopy to deploy my backups.

This is an example of a command:

```
schtasks /Create /SC ONCE /TN $TaskName /TR "robocopy.exe $Source $Target /E /COPY:DAT /V /R:0 /W:0 /LOG+:$LogPfad" /ST $StartTime /SD $StartDate /F
```

The problem is, that when I run my script, the task will appear, but it uses the same text with the same variables

For example, this script will run the task with this command:

```
robocopy.exe $Source $Target /E /COPY:DAT /V /R:0 /W:0 /LOG+:$LogPfad
```

So that the Backup can't run properly.

It should be saved in the task like this:

```
robocopy.exe C:\test\source D:\test\target /E /COPY:DAT /V /R:0 /W:0 /LOG+:$LogPfad
```

There is an option, that I could save the command in a .bat file and execute it, but this shouldn't be the solution.

Would be fantastic, if somebody could help me! :D

Best regards

lucbas

Comment: would you mind posting more of the code you have to create the scheduled task? You should be able to use variables in there. It might help us figure out what's wrong if we have a bigger picture of your code here.

Comment: Of course, but I'm not home currently. I'll paste it in, as soon as I'm at home.

Comment: Great! I'll try to remember to check back after I get home as well.

Comment: Here is the download Link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aiicih4ou22lrsv/BackupAssistantForm1.5.ps1

Comment: Has either of these answers fixed your problem?

Comment: yes both answers from you (iesou) and from Jackie, solved my problem. Thank you both so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code you might want to try something like this:

```
schtasks /Create /SC ONCE /TN $TaskName /TR `"robocopy.exe $QuellPfadRAW $ZielPfad /M /E /COPY:DAT /V /R:0 /W:0 /LOG:$LogPfad`" /ST $StartTime /SD $StartDate /F
```

When you put "s in a Powershell line it takes everything inside of them as literal, meaning variables won't be replaced.

If you put a ` in front of each of your "s it should negate that.

Sorry it took me so long to get back to you btw.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
$taskrun = "`"robocopy.exe $Source $Target /E /COPY:DAT /V /R:0 /W:0 /LOG+:$LogPfad" /ST $StartTime /SD $StartDate`""
schtasks /Create /SC ONCE /TN $taskrun
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer :D Could you explain for what the "`" stay for? Thank you

Comment: The ` is used in powershell to "escape" special characters. Basically it makes powershell ignore them instead of running them as part of the code. You can go here for a better explaination: [http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html)